# Why can't I call asInstanceOf on an object in Scala?

Tags: scala

Is there a way to do an `asInstanceOf` on a Scala `object`. Even though it is a singleton, it is still an instance. So why can't I do an `asInstanceOf` on this singleton?

Say:

```
case object MyObject
```

Comment: Well... the reason is that because its not just a simple singleton object. Though you can think of it as being a singleton object, it is still a "special object" which wraps all the static members of a type.

Comment: Is the difficulty on the scope(s) on referring to an object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can, actually:

```
$ scala
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_39).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> case object MyObject
defined module MyObject

scala> val x: Any = MyObject
x: Any = MyObject

scala> x.asInstanceOf[MyObject.type]
res0: MyObject.type = MyObject
```

Comment: You don't even need the intermediate value. `MyObject.asInstanceOf[...]` compiles and works as it should. I have no idea where scalanomad got the impression that one cannot use `asInstanceOf` on a singleton.

Comment: Absolutely. I just wanted an `Any` specifically not to have a "void" `asInstanceOf`. But you're right, `MyObject.asInstanceOf[MyObject.type]` is just as valid.

Answer (score 0):

By definition a singleton (namely a Scala object) has one only instance, referred by the name used in the object declaration.

Also note that in a class you can refer to the type by the class name itself,

```
case class B()
val b = B()

b.isInstanceOf[B]
res: Boolean = true
```

However a `case object` proves to be a single instance; to refer to its type consider

```
case object A

A.isInstanceOf[A.type]
res: Boolean = true
```